# Doctrine 2, last insert auto increment key inside transaction

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Im creating and persisting (not flushing) data insite a transaction. But `->getId()` returns NULL, while MySql originally can return auto increment value inside transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be null but on `Flush` doctrine will handle all relations properly.

`For the most part, Doctrine 2 already takes care of proper transaction demarcation for you: All the write operations (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) are queued until EntityManager#flush() is invoked which wraps all of these changes in a single transaction.`

Read more here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Comment: Then you need to flush. You will can still rolback transaction